# How to add repeated beeps to sound created with a pause in between each beep in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, sound

I have 2 sounds that I created and trying to make them beeps. Maybe 4 or 5 repeated beeps but have a pause in between each beep but make it still part of the signal. I think I have it so that the sound is a single frequency but just need make it a repeated with pauses and still part of the same signal. Any help would be appreciated I have the code listed below.

```
Fs = 44100;
N = 400;
t = (1:N)*(1/Fs);
freq = 600;

sound_array = zeros(N, 2);
%starts N x 2 matrix
sound_array(:,1) = sin(2*pi*freq*t);
sound_array(:,2) = sin(2*pi*freq*t);

%Left and Right channels

sound_L = sound_array;
sound_L(:,2) = 0;
sound_R = sound_array;
sound_R(:,1) = 0;
plot(sound_array);

%Sound 1
sound(sound_L, Fs);
%Sound 2
sound(sound_R, Fs);
%Play consecutive
sound(sound_array, Fs);
```

Comment: Can you next time past the source code, instead of taking its screenshot?

Comment: yes @jojek...how do I paste the source code on here?

Comment: Just take a while and look closer to the toolbar in editing mode. You know how to insert image, then the icon next to it is meant to insert preformatted code. One last thing - mind to accept answers after getting an answer. If you again don't know how, then please take a [**tour**](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any pause can be done by using vector/matrix concatenation. Let's say you want to make a signal with pause of length `P` after it, then do the following:

```
P = 400;
beep = [sound_array; zeros(P, 2)];
```

Now if you want to make arbitrary number `K` of your beeps then use the [**repmat**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/repmat.html) function as follows:

```
K = 5;
beeps = repmat(beep, K, 1);
```

Please read more about matrix concatenation [**here**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html) if you wish.

I believe that with your current code, because you use `sound` function, signals will be played at the same time. I suggest you to use the [**pause**](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/pause.html) function to separate playbacks, i.e.:

```
sound(...)
pause(1)
sound(...)
```

To create a 1 second pause between playback starts.

Comment: using the P = 400 what does the 400 represent @jojek

Comment: @Asau7610: Same what `N=400` in your original code.